# EWS Schema information not found

Tags: c#, xml, soap, exchangewebservices

I am trying to connect an Xamarin.Android C# program to an Exchange 2013 server via Exchange WebService (EWS). I send the following XML file (dynamically created using `XmlTextWriter`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Header>
  <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
  <m:GetRoomLists xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" />
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and receive this answer (minus formatting):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body>
  <s:Fault>
   <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation</faultcode>
   <faultstring xml:lang="de-DE">Fehler bei der Schemaüberprüfung der Anforderung: Die Schemainformationen für das Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages:GetRoomLists' konnten nicht gefunden werden.</faultstring>
   <detail>
    <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode>
    <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">Fehler bei der Schemaüberprüfung der Anforderung.</e:Message>
    <t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
     <t:LineNumber>7</t:LineNumber>
     <t:LinePosition>6</t:LinePosition>
     <t:Violation>Die Schemainformationen für das Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages:GetRoomLists' konnten nicht gefunden werden.</t:Violation>
    </t:MessageXml>
   </detail>
  </s:Fault>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The error texts translate roughly to "Error while checking request scheme" (`<e:Message>`) and "Scheme information for element '`<URL>:GetRoomLists`' could not be found" (`<t:Violation>`); `<faultstring>` is the combination of both.

I don't understand where the error lies. Is my request XML bad, is the Exchange Server misconfigured or is a module missing (if so, which one?), is there some other error?

I've tried several other things in the SOAP body, e.g. `<GetRooms><RoomList><EmailAddress>room@server</EmailAddress></RoomList></GetRooms>`, with the same error message (complaining about `GetRooms`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is versioned to Exchange 2007 SP1, but GetRoomLists wasn't available until Exchange 2010. If you're using a version of Exchange that's 2010 or later, try changing your `RequestServerVersion` element to `Exchange2010`.